# Github pages not showing website content and error 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I deployed my react app on github pages, my website consumes multiple API to show content. When I deployed my react app on github pages the website is empty. Another problem I have is when redirecting to another route for example: https://username.github.io/movies or even https://username.github.io/website/movies, I get this error:

```
404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

If you're trying to publish one, read the full documentation to learn how to set up GitHub Pages for your repository, organization, or user account.
```

my package.json:

```
"homepage": "https://username.github.io/website",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your react app off of Github pages if you make sure to use history manipulation for your links instead of real links. You can either write your own Link component that wraps an a tag and will perform a history.push on click instead of letting the browser handle the linking or you can use something like the HashRouter from react-router.

If someone enters your site via the /something link, github will try to load the corresponding file from your repo, which isn't there.

That also means any direct/hotlinks to your site will only work for static pages and not for dynamically generated content from your React App.

Comment: Looks like they changed the behaviour of the Link component to just render normal anchor tags if possible. Could be I mix up react-router with the redux version of it, though. One of them used to perform a history.push operation on click of a link component instead of letting the browser handle the navigation.